# How to check if the last row in a MySQL table has required value?

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I was thinking about implementing a state table in MySQL for several Bash scripts to poll. The idea is that script *#n* is cleared to run once script *#n-1* has finished running and has written its state and status into the state table in a MySQL db. Basically the state table would look like:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | state | status |
+----+-------+--------+
| 44 |     2 |   OK   |
| 45 |     3 |   OK   |
| .. |   ... |  ...   |
| 55 |     2 |   OK   |
+----+-------+--------+
```

The `id` column is `auto_increment` so that can be used to define the last row.

At the moment I've come up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
#...
VARIABLE=$(mysql mydbname --skip-column-names -s --local -e \
         "SELECT count(*) \
          FROM statetable \
          WHERE state=2 AND \
                status='OK' AND \
                id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM statetable)")
if [ $VARIABLE -eq 1 ] ; then #...
```

Is there a right way to check if the last row in the table has the wanted state value and status pair (2 and OK in the example above) without a subquery and to pass that information to the Bash script?

ADDED SOLUTION:

```
#!/bin/bash
function check_state () {
    VARIABLE=$(mysql mydbname --skip-column-names -s --local -e \
             "SELECT (state=2) && (status='OK') \
              FROM statetable \
              ORDER BY id DESC \
              LIMIT 1;")
    return $VARIABLE
}

if ! check_state ; then #...
```

Comment: I would select them by `DESC ID` and `LIMIT 2`. This will give you 2 rows - the second one will hold all your data to check against the other the "next job to run" stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you can select not only fields, but also expressions and operations on them. Somewhat surprisingly this works for logical tests as well, the kind we use, for example in a `where` clause. That means that you could use the following SQL to get a boolean (0 / 1) result:

```
select (state = 2) && (status = 'OK')
from statetable
order by id desc
limit 1
```

You can try it out on this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ff48/3).

Sorry that I did not understand the question at first, but as it seems everybody did :)

<s>The query you have written will most likely always return a value of 1, because it does not select the maximum id, it selects the number of rows with a maximum id, and if there is at least one row in the table, there is such a thing as a maximum id :)</s>

Assuming that you need the last ID, a better way (without a subquery) would be to order the data, and just take the first row, something like:

```
SELECT id FROM statetable 
WHERE state=2 
  AND status='OK' 
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return the last pair of 2 and OK regardless of it being on the last row?

Comment: Since it's ordered by ID DESC, that last row with a pair of 2 and OK will have a maximum ID, which is what you want.

Comment: No, I'm trying to check if the last row in the table has the desired state and status. It works if this is the condition but if the last known state and status are for example 1 and OK, the query will return the last instance of 2 and OK.

Comment: Aha, I guess I read the question wrong, will update the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

u can also do it like that

```
  SELECT MAX(id) ,state , status FROM statetable WHERE state=2 AND status='OK'
```

like that u prevent the sql from checking two times ,

**EDIT**

```
  SELECT EXISTS(SELECT MAX(id) ,state , status FROM statetable WHERE state=2 AND status='OK' ) getIt from statetable
```

Comment: This returns the max id where state and status are 2 and ok. I need to check if the last state and status are 2 and ok.

Comment: and if the last id is 2 and ok then what u will do ? if they right

Comment: If the script #2 has ended successfully (state=2, status='OK') script #3 executes. Therefore I need to check the last row in the status table to see if it's 2 and OK. Since I wasn't going to clean the table after every script, I can't rely on your solution (which was actually my first shot at the title).

Comment: cant you check it by php or bash or something else . ? if (....) then run what u want , else .....

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is,

```
VARIABLE=$(mysql mydbname --skip-column-names -s --local -e "SELECT MAX(id) ,state , status FROM statetable WHERE state=2 AND status='OK'")
if [ $VARIABLE -nq 0 ] ; then #...
```

Comment: In the next step we need to check if variable is not equal to 0. Since he is new to sql I just guided him.. NO issues right